# Toggle icon symbol on click using js

Tags: javascript, html

In this menu, I'm trying to change the "+" symbol to "-" on click, but I don't know how to proceed. It will be a button that I'll change to custom icons later...

html

```
<header id="header">
      <div class="header-container">
        <p id="logo">Logo</p>
        <nav id="nav">
          <div id="btn-mobile">+</div>
          <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Trabalhos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Carreiras</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

js

```
const btnMobile = document.getElementById('btn-mobile');

function toggleMenu() {
  const nav = document.getElementById('nav');
  nav.classList.toggle('active');
}

btnMobile.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
```

thanks!

Comment: have you heard of `innerText` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you got to do is use `innerText` on your `btn-mobile`

```
const btnMobile = document.getElementById('btn-mobile');

function toggleMenu() {
  const nav = document.getElementById('nav');
  const btnMobile = document.getElementById('btn-mobile');
  nav.classList.toggle('active');
  btnMobile.innerText = '-';
  
}

btnMobile.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
```

or `textContent`, both does almost the same job, there's just some minor difference.
Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

MDN is a great place to learn these basic JS DOM method.

Comment: Thank you, it works! But it only works once, when I click again the icon does not return to the "+" symbol  :(

Comment: This has never been a requirement. You can open a second question for this problem if you need help with it.

Comment: @eaesergio agree with what @cloned said. Use logic to change the + to - and back and forth simply by checking the current value of the `btn-mobile` if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `i` and use css class to set the content of `+` or `-`

```js
const btnMobile = document.getElementById('icon');

function toggleMenu() {
  if (btnMobile.classList.contains('icon-plus')) {
    btnMobile.classList.remove('icon-plus');
    btnMobile.classList.add('icon-minus')
  } else if (btnMobile.classList.contains('icon-minus')) {
    btnMobile.classList.remove('icon-minus');
    btnMobile.classList.add('icon-plus')

  }
}

btnMobile.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
```

```css
.icon-plus:after {
  content: '+';
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon-minus:after {
  content: '-';
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="header-container">
    <p id="logo">Logo</p>
    <nav id="nav">
      <div id="btn-mobile">
        <i id='icon' class="icon icon-plus"></i>
      </div>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trabalhos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Carreiras</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```